# Parallelize without Task.Run()

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, async-await

Is it possible to let something run in background (in example a DB query) without spawining new thread with Task.Run()?

Example Db query

```
public async Task Query(long objectToDelete)
{
    using ( var ctx= new Context())
    {
        Car car = new Car { Id = objectToDelete};

        ctx.Entry(employer).State = EntityState.Deleted;

        await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

From what I understand the Query is runned synchronously up until the first "await", then the control is returned to the caller,

I wonder if I can leave a caller like that:

```
public async Task Caller( long id)
{
    var runningQuery = Query( id);

    /* do something else

    */

    // await runningQuery; // commented out so "Caller" can complete early
}
```

Comment: Please specify which project you have like its a windows form, web api, console, or any other

Comment: it is a ASP.NET project, so the query is inside a GET

Comment: @UberFace - And what happened when you tried your code in the "wonder" part of your question?

Comment: As long as "do something else" doesn't rely on the result of the `Task` in `runningQuery`, or any state changes it might make, this is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do exactly this. The query is running as soon as `SaveChangesAsync` returns. `await` pauses execution until the task is done. So don't use await (you did this correctly).

Note, that fire and forget work is very difficult. You need to make sure to log errors. Also, you often cannot rely on the work to ever complete. There might be an error (like a network blip or a deadlock or a timeout) or your whole process might exit before the query is complete. This is especially relevant in ASP.NET. Consider fire and forget work optional if you do not wait for it at any point.

Answer (score 1):

The await keyword will halt execution within the method that it is called and return execution to the method that called that method. So if you wanted to return from "Caller" early, you would just leave the

```
await runningQuery;
```

in place.

This Microsoft [Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) explains it. If you look at the diagram under the heading  [What Happens in an Async Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/#BKMK_WhatHappensUnderstandinganAsyncMethod) , you get a good visual reference of the logic flow.